# jQuery addClass to all img in summernote data

Tags: jquery, summernote

I want to add img-responsive to all img in some HTML that I get from summernote text. I thought this would work, but it does not. Perhaps because the img tag does not have a class attribute?

Example of the html

```
<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI...."></p>
```

Here is my code:

```
var rawHtml = $("#summernote").summernote('code');
$(rawHtml).find('img').each(function () {
  $('img').addClass('img-responsive');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: Error fixed. It should work now

You need to get `code` back to `#summernote`.
Try this one:

```
 var rawHtml = $($('#summernote').summernote('code'));
 rawHtml.find('img').each(function () {
        $('img').addClass('img-responsive');
    });
 $('#summernote').summernote('code', 
    rawHtml.html();
 );
```

Comment: please, check again.

Answer (score 3):

```js
// v 0.8.9
$('#summernote').summernote({
  callbacks: {
      onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
      //find images on note-editable class, 
      var imgs = $('.note-editable').find("img");
        $.each(imgs, function(index, img){
           //bootstrap 3
           $(img).addClass("img-responsive");
           
           //bootstrap 4
           //$(img).addClass("img-fluid");
        })
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: OnChange i have memory problems, better event onBlur.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
var rawHtml = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
$('#summernote').find('img').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('img-responsive');
});
```

Or even simpler:

```
var rawHtml = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
$('#summernote img').addClass('img-responsive');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both and neither worked for me. For some reason the image was corrupt. I got [object][object] or nothing when displaying the content.

I tried a simple string replace and it worked. Probably would work on editing the data afterwards as well.

This worked.

```
    var rawHtml = $("#summernote").summernote('code');
    var imgResp = rawHtml.replace('<img src=', '<img class="img-responsive" src=');
    var description = encodeURIComponent(imgResp);

    var record = {
        EventId: $('#EventId').val(),
        Title: $('#EventTitle').val(),
        Start: $('#Start').val(),
        End: $('#End').val(),
        IsActive: $('#IsActive').prop('checked'),
        IsFullDay: $('#IsFullDay').prop('checked'),
        Description: description
    };
```